# Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection Service won't start and unable to change Startup Type from Manual

Tags: windows, anti-virus, windows-11, windows-defender

(I'm running Windows 11)

Windows Defender is running and Real-time protection is turned on according to the Windows Security settings page.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7taes.png)

The screenshot shows the highlighted service from `services.msc` as disabled and the windows defender real-time protection and other virus & threat protection settings as turned on. Windows Defender shows 0 issues, green check marks all around.
Why is it that the Windows  Defender Advanced Threat Protection Service is turned off and unable to be started manually? It quickly fails after trying to start it with this error message: `The Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection Service service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if tey are not in use by other services or programs`.. I have no other antivirus installed, I only use Windows Defender.

I am also unable to change the Startup Type to `Automatically`, the operation fails with Access Denied.
Should I be concerned by this? Is this a sign of a malware infection, or is this normal configuration? (I ran a full scan and it came back clean).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it that the Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection Service
> is turned off and unable to be started manually? It quickly fails
> after trying to start it with this error message:

This appears to be normal behavior of the Threat Protection Service in Windows 11 (more so than Windows 10).  I have two Windows 11 Pro machines here and 1 Windows 10 Pro.

The threat protection service in Windows 11 is normally OFF and is off (stopped automatically) if not in use. There are other Local Group Policies (gpedit.msc) that affect the operation.

I know Windows 11 Defender is working because it quarantined some apps I use (unlocker 1.92) that I had to whitelist.

There are numerous articles about this, not all conclusive. Here is a good and fairly recent Microsoft Article that is somewhat helpful

[Windows Defender](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/virus-threat-protection-in-windows-security-1362f4cd-d71a-b52a-0b66-c2820032b65e)

So at this point, situation normal for Services.  Of course it may change as Defender changes to adapt to new threats.

Windows Defender Security center shows Windows Defender working properly in Windows 11 and in Windows 10.

Comment: Ultimately the real status of Windows Defender will be listed in Windows Security.

Comment: Security Settings show this but not the Services at this point in Windows 11. Post adjusted.

Comment: My point is that, the status of the service, isn’t necessarily important if Windows Security says Defender is working

Comment: Yes and my post says that in a slightly different way.

Comment: Thank you for the article and the response! I was having trouble finding one myself.

Comment: The article posted seemed to me to be the best of what I saw.